# Custom font size nav bar

Tags: customization, menus

I'm trying to increase the font size on my nav bar.

I'm using Monstroid2. http://new.cascaderelays.com/

I'm guessing I'll need to add custom css somewhere. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your current activate theme style.css in put this css

```
.main-navigation ul li a {
    font-size: 16px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nav#site-navigation li a {font-size: 16px;}
```

- There must be some option in your theme to add custom CSS. Add the
  above code there.
- You can also go to Appearance > Editor and add the above code in the
  style.css of your theme. (please be careful with this as one wrong
  character can break your site)
- If you have FTP access to the site goto
  wp-content/themes/Monstroid2/, download the style.css and add the
  above code.

> Note: change the 16px to whatever size you want.